# MVC JQuery Authentication not working on a single page app

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I have a sign in form,

```
@if (@User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
   <div>Welcome @User.Identity.Name</div> 
}
else
{
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge">
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge">
    <button id="loginBtn" class="btn btn-success">Login</button>
}
```

Some JQuery,

```
$("#loginBtn").click(function () {
    Authenticate();            
});

function Authenticate() {
    $.post("/Home/Authenticate", { username: "John", password: "test" }, function (data) {
        $('#loginArea').replaceWith(data);
    });
}
```

And some server side code to handle the request.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Authenticate(string username, string password)
{

    var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
        1,
        username,
        DateTime.Now,
        DateTime.Now.AddDays(5),
        true,
        string.Empty,
        FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

    var encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

    Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket));

    return PartialView("_login");
}
```

The strange thing is, this works, but not on the initial call. The returned View is not updated even through the user is authenticated. If I refresh the page, everything works as expect. The problem is, this is a single page app, and I really don't want to force a page refresh..

Is there a reason why the returned PartialView doesn't render the "Welcome" text?

Comment: Are you setting the logged in user or just manually sending a cookie back to the client?

Comment: My understanding was that adding the Cookie was "logging the user in". Is there someone else which needs to be done server side?

Comment: I think sending the cookie back will log the user in once the server receives it, but since the cookie is in the response and not the request, for purposes of *this* request, the User.Identity will still not be populated. Not sure of a direct answer, but two workarounds I can think of are to 1)use a property on the model for "justAuthenticated" or something, or 2)do an additional round-trip AJAX call from the client which will then include the cookie

Comment: Hopefully someone will have the "real" answer though. Out of curiosity is there a specific reason you're manually issuing authentication tickets and cookies instead of using a provider?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie() Require a Redirect?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10190634/does-formsauthentication-setauthcookie-require-a-redirect)  (Yes, because the request that sets a cookie will not be authenticated, therefore a new asp.net pipeline is required to authenticate the user)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only subsequent requests are authenticated since they contain the forms authentication cookie in the request.

So on the initial call I needed to be careful not to use the current Principal.